# phpPgAdmin: how to duplicate an exact table from one database to another

Tags: sql, database, datatable, create-table, phppgadmin

[image]

Just as the title says, I want to duplicate one table from a completely separate database in phpPgAdmin to another one. I have tried two ways but both did not work for me:

1. Tried "Create table like" (database >> table >> create table like)

   - this seems to can only duplicate a table within the database
2. Tried export and import

   - I tried to export the table I want, then heading over to the other database and try to import in an empty table. but the error i am getting is either "Import error: File could not be uploaded to the server phppgadmin" or "Import error: Failed to automatically determine the file format."

Comment: tag your database as well, I assume It's postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pg_dump` , which extract PostgreSQL database/table and the pipe it directly to another server/database

```
pg_dump -t table_name source_db | psql target_db
```

for more info read [pg_dump documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html).